# Manage custom list, Workflow History and Tasks

Tags: list, workflow

Is there a tool or procedure to manage completed workflows and its associates such as Tasks and Workflow History Lists ?

The Custom List, Task List and History List has grown hugely. Custom List contains 8000 items, Task List contains 13,000 items and Workflow History List contains 80,000 items as a result workflows have started to fail.

Ideally I want to move the Item and its associates to an Archive List.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar problem with my SP team today! For a specific list in a workflow navigate to:

Settings>> Information Management Policy Settings>> WorkFlow History
Retention settings allow Stage property changes to configure when to archive or delete a list item.

Good luck!